# CentOS 7 GCC won't compile

Tags: linux, installation, centos-7, gcc

I'm running CentOS 7 on a Dell Precision T3400. I have installed the Cacti network monitoring tool and am trying to install Spine, the last critical binary. I've downloaded Spine and am attempting to install it using:

```
cd /tmp/(spine directory)
./bootstrap
./configure
make
make install
```

However when I attempt to run `./configure` I receive this output:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/cacti-spine-0.8.8h':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
see config.log
```

The `config.log` says:

```
build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='unknown'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /tmp/cacti-spine-0.8.8h/config/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##
/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "Spine Poller"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "spine-poller"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.8.8h"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "Spine Poller 0.8.8h"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://www.cacti.net/bugs.php"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "spine"
#define VERSION "0.8.8h"

configure: exit 77
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Install "a complete gcc compiler" `# yum install gcc-c++` . I.e. gcc-c++ takes care of installing the missing packages `glibc-devel, glibc-headers, kernel-headers` .

Comment: will implement on Monday when I can get back to the machine, thanks for the help

Comment: after attempting, I found I had already had gcc-c++ installed, I tried all of the packages separately and they were already installed as well

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue, turns out what was missing was `net-snmp-devel` and `openssl-devel`if anyone else runs into this problem.

Answer (score -1):

May be the `./bootstrap` command is messing up the already perfect `configure` script in `cacti-spine-0.8.8h/` https://www.cacti.net/downloads/spine/cacti-spine-0.8.8h.tar.gz

Requirement : `# yum install mariadb-devel`

Solution : Unpack a new `cacti-spine-0.8.8h.tar.gz`

```
cd cacti-spine-0.8.8h/
./configure
make
# make install
```

... No issues here, CentOS 7.4.1708 .